# Visual Studio 2008 and 2008 SP1 Addin: using EnvDTE90 and EnvDTE90a

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, add-in, breakpoints, visual-studio-addins

Does anyone know the equivalent for doing this in Visual Studio 2008([EnvDTE90](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513943.aspx)) and Visual Studio 2008 SP1([EnvDTE90a](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte90a.aspx))?

```
    //this is code for Visual Studio 2005, works great
    EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
    GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0");

    foreach (EnvDTE80.Breakpoint2 bp in dte2.Debugger.Breakpoints)
    {
         //do some things
    }
```

I have done normal google searches and found various things, but none of them worked.

[EnvDTE90.Debugger3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513943.aspx) seems to only work if actively debugging.  I want to access breakpoints at anytime?

NOTE: Please don't send links to existing code examples that SHOULD work.  I have tried all that I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got some code working. KristoferA's answer is partially correct in that the same API can be used, but the code would not work verbatim.  This is how I got it to work:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.
GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0");

foreach (EnvDTE80.Breakpoint2 bp in dte2.Debugger.Breakpoints)
{
     //do some things
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The VS2005 code (EnvDTE80) should work fine with VS2008 too. EnvDTE90 just adds some new functionality but EnvDTE80 and EnvDTE are still needed for the basics.

Comment: My same VS 2005 code will not run in VS 2008 that you see in the question.